# Position space Feynman rules to momentum space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

For example consider $2\to2$ scattering in scalar $\phi^4$ theory.
When the in/out coming positions are fixed, it is easy to calculate in terms of contractions. When we fix the incoming / outgoing momenta instead, how can we use the Feynman rules in that case?

In principle one can expand all the fields in terms of creation/annihilation operators and pull them through but how is this procedure generalised using the knowledge on position space correlation functions?